# Get IP of the frontend user in TYPO3 10

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I need the IP of the frontend user in a validator for `tx_form`. In older TYPO3 version I used `GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv()` for this. How can I achieve this in TYPO3 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this with `GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('REMOTE_ADDR');` just as you did before.

Comment: ⚠ But this does not take `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP headers into account as far as I know. Use it with caution if your TYPO3 instance is behind a proxy, load balancer, CDN, or use a server-side solution such as `mod_remoteip` in Apache.

Comment: It respects such stuff but you need to tell TYPO3 about the proxy, e.g. using `reverseProxyIP` and all those other settings in the Install Tool